# How to connect external camera in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I need to connect external camera to take video/picture. So, instead of on device camera I have to use the external camera which is connected thru USB.

Answer (score 0):

This package will solve your problem but its for web only right now https://pub.dev/packages/usb_device

Comment: Hi Piyush, Thanks for the update!! I would need to connect the external camera into an android device. Also, I tried this package to check whether I could able access the external camera. Yes, I can able to connect using this package, but cannot able to stream the video!!